# How to use rowiterator in apache poi with java?

Tags: java, row, apache-poi, hssf

I tried to read an excel file using apache poi in java, however, Eclipse did not compile  the code.

```
public class ReadExcel {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXal\\042012.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();

        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {

        Row row = rowIterator().next();      \\ THIS LINE GETS UNDERLINED BY ECLIPSE!!!
         Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");

                            }

        }
        file.close();
        FileOutputStream out =
            new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
        }


    }
```

Eclipse always underlines `Row row = rowIterator().next();` line. I do not know why? How can I improve it?

Comment: Try to remove the bracket from this line    Row row = rowIterator.next(); instead of it  Row row = rowIterator().next();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is not with eclipse, it is with the code. You can not treat rowIterator which is a variable, as a method. You can not invoke a variable with the () syntax.

Try this:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXal\\042012.xls"));
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(file);
    HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
      Row row = rowIterator.next();
      Iterator <Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
      while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
        Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
      }
    }
    file.close();
    FileOutputStream out =
      new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));
    wb.write(out);
    out.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to remove the "()" after rowIterator.

Instead of:

```
rowIterator().next();
```

It should be:

```
rowIterator.next()
```

Answer (score 5):

In this line:

```
Row row = rowIterator().next();
```

You are attempting to call a method called `rowIterator` on your own class, which of course you don't have.

From the context it's clear you meant to refer to the `rowIterator` variable you already have.  Change it to:

```
Row row = rowIterator.next();  // No () on rowIterator
```