# How to get results from specific position in an excel file using apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I have an excel file which contains various information and also contains a table structure which has two headers unit code and description.So now i am able to read the whole excel file using POI,but my problem is that i need to read  only the two values of the coloumns of the table in excel.But i am not able to properly doing that,Here is my code  what i have done so far.

```
public class ReadExcelFileToList {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    InputStream input = null;

    try {

        input = new FileInputStream(
                "C:\\Users\\jeet.chatterjee\\Downloads\\unitUploadFormat.xlsx");

        System.out.println("file is found");

        XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(input);
        XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        int rowCount = 0;
        Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
            System.out.println("\n");
            if (rowCount == 3) {
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

                while (cells.hasNext()) {

                    XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                    if (XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING == cell.getCellType())
                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()
                                + "     ");

                    /*
                     * else if (XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING ==
                     * cell.getCellType())
                     * System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() +
                     * "     "); else if (XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING ==
                     * cell.getCellType())
                     * System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() +
                     * "     ");
                     */

                    else
                        System.out.print("Unknown cell type");

                }
                rowCount++;
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        input.close();
    }

}

}
```

i am using  sheet.getLastRowNum()  to get my desired  result,But i am not getting it somebody please help.[image: here is my excel file]. This is my excel file i just want to get kg & kilogram values and so on ,all the items which will be putted there  will be extrated.

Comment: use the rowIterator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19280956/how-to-use-rowiterator-in-apache-poi-with-java

Comment: rowIterator i am already using

Comment: so what are you getting?

Comment: Please insert data from 5th row      

Use only Unit code & Unit column     QUOTATION_RFQ_STATE     



UNIT CODE     DESCRIPTION     

KG     KILOGRAM

Comment: the whole excel i am getting

Comment: thats because the rowCount++ is in the wrong location. move it before the end of outer while loop and you should be good to ge

Comment: did you see my updated answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 while (rows.hasNext()) {
            XSSFRow row = (XSSFRow) rows.next();
            if(rowCount==3){
            Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
            while (cells.hasNext()) {
                XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) cells.next();
                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+"\t");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            rowCount++;
        }
```

like what Scary Wombat said, use your own counter for rows.

Comment: i am updating the post with ur suggestion

Answer (score 0):

The error in you code is explained by the API for getLastRowNum

> Returns: last row contained n this sheet (0-based)

so you want

```
if(rowCount == 4){
```

but of course if there are empty rows, the result may also not be what you want.

**Edit**

By why make it so difficult.

Use

```
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(4);
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(1)
```

Comment: i am not getting the result